How to get a full coverage report using OpenCppCoverage?
I have a C++ project and an associated Google Test C++ project with tests.
I run this...
OpenCppCoverage --sources C:\src\MyApp\ -- .\x64\Debug\MyApp.Tests.exe

I can see the coverage report fine, but it only includes files loaded by MyApp.Tests.exe. I'd like to see all files in C:\src\MyApp\ included in the report, since MyApp.Tests.exe doesn't test all files and that's why I need the coverage report! :)
How do I include all source files in C:\src\MyApp\ when creating the coverage report?

Maybe they are just not linked into MyApp.Tests.exe executable

That's the problem, the tests executable is only including code that's tested. Code that's not tested isn't included in the coverage report, which is the whole point of code coverage reporting!

Try /OPT:NOREF linker flag. This should work if your test project includes all the sources. That may not work if you link your Test project with static lib of the TestApp. In case of static lib, you should force linker to access every translation module of the lib file by referencing some random symbol (function or global variable) from the Test project code
